# How can I bind the Text property of a label to a property of the .SelectedValue of a ComboBox and have it update when that value changes?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox, datasource

I've a ComboBox that is bound to a changing list of users. That list can change based on the filter preferences of the user. The ComboBox itself displays only the users name, but I have several labels which I would like to display various values of the user selected in the ComboBox.

I've already noticed that it doesn't work as when I set the filters to return nothing, the combobox is supposed to be given a dummy datasource (a simple anonymous object with property values that meet the criteria for the combobox .DisplayMember property, as well as the values to which the labels are bound).

I would like the labels text to change whenever the user selects another user from the ComboBox.

I know the reason binding the labels to the ComboBox.SelectedValue isn't working is because it just binds their properties to the properties of the object at the time the binding is set. I kind of figured that was the case.

I know that this probably isn't the ideal way to go about it (Likely that would be just adding an event handler to the ValueChanged event and reading the value data into the labels), but, really for fun more than anything else, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

### EDIT:

Here's some relevant code :

```
//Assigning Combobox Datasource
List<TableEntries.User> Users =
    Tables.GetUsers( this.chkGetUnregistered.Checked, this.chkGetUnconfirmed.Checked );
if ( Users != null && Users.Count > 0 )
    this.cbxUserNames.DataSource = Users;

//DataBinding .Text properties of labels to .SelectedValue property of the ComboBox
this.lblCompany.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.cbxUserNames.SelectedValue, "UserCompany");
this.lblEmail.DataBindings.add("Text", this.cbxUserNames.SelectedValue, "UserEmail");
this.lblPhone.DataBindings.add("Text", this.cbxUserName.SelectedValue, "UserPhone");
```

I know that the easiest method is just

```
this.cbxUserNames.SelectedValueChanged += (s,e) => {
    this.lblCompany.Text = (this.cbxUserNames.SelectedValue as TableEntries.User).UserCompany
    this.lblEmail.Text = ...
    this.lblPhone.Text = ...
};
```

and that's how I have it now. And I know the way it works is that the selectedvalue object doesn't actually change, it just kind of goes away. The properties of that value don't change. So I was hoping that I could figure a way to make the labels "smart" enough to say "Hey, the .SelectedValue property changed, we should probably look at the new object"

Comment: ... in .Net WinForms? What?

Comment: sorry man, i thought it said webforms at quick glance

Comment: Try showing us the pertinent code if you want help with this.